# Normalizing selection of dataframe columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` with variables `var1` `var2` (both strings) and variables `x`, `y`, and `z`. I would like to normalize variables `x`, `y` and `z` by dividing them all by their respective first element.

I tried:

```
df_ %>% 
  mutate_at(c("x", "y", "z"), funs(./.[1])) %>% head()
```

But, this sets the whole column to 1. How can I achieve that it devides by the first element?

Secondly, what is the best way to add the normalized to the dataframe as variables `x_norm`, `y_norm`, `z_norm`?

Many thanks, and please let me know in case you need further info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be a problem with the attributes or grouping variable.  We can reset the dataset without external attributes by converting to `data.frame` and then do the `mutate_at`

```
df_ %>% 
   as.data.frame %>%
   mutate_at(vars(x, y, z), funs(norm = ./.[1]))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, thanks. But, this does not work for me, I am still getting a column of all 1s.

Comment: @clog14 Could you please check  the `str(df_)`?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you let me know for what exactly? I find that the variables are numeric. I also find `attr(*, "vars")= chr "date"`. Is this relevant?

Comment: @clog14 Suppose you provided an example `set.seed(24);
df_ <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 4 * 10, replace = TRUE), 10, 4, 
          dimnames = list(NULL, c("v", "x", "y", "z"))))`  It is not creating a column of all 1s

Comment: thanks. You are absolutely right. Do you know which part of the `str(df_)` would help?

Comment: @clog14  I would assume that you have some grouping variable or attributes creating trouble.  Try this `df_ %>% as.data.frame %>%  mutate_at(vars(c("x", "y", "z")), funs(norm = ./.[1]))`

Comment: Thanks, akrun. That did work. Do you have an idea how I could identify what the problem was?

Comment: @clog14 as you didn't provide a reproducible example, it is not clear how you got into this problem.  It happens when you do some kind of transformations that also creates attributes and prevent some function to work.  BTW, are you using the newer version of dplyr?

Comment: Yes, you are write about the example. I will see if I can produce one, but going to have to do some anonymization... I am using dplyr 0.7.4 according to `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: so, your package is recent version.  I still think it could be due to some attributes

Answer (score 2):

Building on @akrun's answer, you can also use the `first()` function from `dplyr`:

```
df_ %>%
        mutate_at(vars(c("x", "y", "z")), funs(norm = ./first(.)))
```